# Video-Calling Over WiFi without any intermediate server or 3rd party connection like Skype

Tags: android, video-streaming, wifi

I want to facilitate video-calling from the android device to another android device. My question is that can i connect the android WiFi device with the android WiFi device without any use of internet connection. I want to use it just like the Skype. is this possible or not? if it is possible then how can i implement it...can i get some code snippets as well???? Please give me link to download that app

Comment: Do you *actually* want to set up an ad-hoc WiFi network between the two devices, so you can make a VoIP call? Given the average WiFi range (tens of meters/hundreds of feet), wouldn't it be easier just to shout? ;)

Comment: actually a given WiFi network(WLAN) can extend from a few metres to even some kilometres...i dont think u,or any one for that matter, can shout for kilometres....

Comment: @user750416: The kilometre range is achievable with special, properly calibrated equipment and directional antennas, and even then it's no walk in the park (as you'll run into interference, latency, Fresnel zones and other unpleasantness, not to mention legal limits on maximum transmit power - 802.11b/g/n was never intended as a long-range comms medium). You *definitely* can't get a kilometer range with an integrated (i.e. weak and omnidirectional) antenna like a smartphone has.

Comment: @piskvor: this range can be achieved by using long-range WiFis...chk-out this link for further info-http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Long-range_Wi-Fi...actually thats the project i hav been assigned so no matter what the range...and i hav to do it to graduate...

Comment: @user750416: See those dishes in the article? Those are the directional antennae; do your devices have anything like that?

Comment: Want real case? We're running a hotel with several floors and garden area. All covered with WiFi. But the internet connection is unreliable. Cellular - expensive. What would you do??
PS: It is a reasonable question.

Answer (score 1):

First, your idea works completely different from Skype, which is completely dependent on a functional Internet connection for its core functionality.

Second, while you *could* create an ad-hoc WiFi network betweeen two Android devices, their range will be the limiting factor:

- WiFi is intended as a short-range wireless medium. There's a reason nobody wanted the 2.4 GHz band (and therefore it is unlicensed): there's a *significant* [noise](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electromagnetic_interference_at_2.4_GHz) and signal loss on these frequencies, noticeable even at short range.
- Moreover, wireless equipment in mobile devices is engineered for power efficiency - which translates to lower broadcast power when compared to on-the-grid devices.
- Also, the antennae in such devices are omnidirectional - this is rather useful for normal use, but again lowers your available broadcast power
- Even if you had huge, high-quality directional external antennae connected to each device, pointing *very precisely* at each other (btw that also means each of them is stuck in one place; [see e.g. this for a dish size calculator](http://www.swisswireless.org/wlan_calc_en.html)), you'd need to make some pretty drastic changes to their networking stack, as the latency inherent in long-distance comms will screw up TCP/IP pretty badly.
- Even so, the setup would be very brittle, dependent even on the weather (water vapour absorbs significant amount of power in that part of the spectrum).

Comment: my proj actually is for a corporate house with a center scaling a few sq.kms....so i actually have to design n implement it across that few sq.kms of WLAN setup using WiFi...\n I am tired of discussing this problem and its drawbacks and stuff...so can we just skip to the part where we discuss the solution???

Comment: @user750416: "Just show me how to do it, I don't care that it's not possible to do this as I described it!" - am I imagining things, or did you say something very much like this? I'm not testing how long you can hold out, I honestly believe that what you are asking is not possible. BTW, you have described a **completely** different setup in your comment than in your question - you did ask for a direct connection, and suddenly *poof*, there's *also* a WLAN mesh or something. What other crucial details did you omit from the question?

Comment: i never meant something like dat....i jus need help and i think dats what everyone does over here-"helping everyone else"...forget about evrything else...i meant dat i want to create a video-calling app on a wifi network and i request help from everyone else regarding this including u

Comment: @user750416: Ah, glad that got straightened out. So, you basically want a LAN VoIP app, if I *now* understand the requirements correctly? Hmm, that's several problems, each of which would warrant its own question: the devices need to *find* each other on the network (broadcasts? or small server?), then you need *call control*, and lastly the audio/video *streaming*; that's not to mention the UI. I suspect you'll need to break these areas down into more specific subproblems before you get to the level where it makes sense to write code...

Comment: ya ur exactly ryt that i want a LAN VoIP app..i need call control where-in the devices would be able to interact(or videocall) through a static ip of that android handset...i hav brokn it down to three parts....1>findin suitable wi-fi connection(completed)...2>makin a video-record-n-playback app(completed)...3>establishin a connection between the devices...4>live duplex video-streaming....steps 3 n 4 hav to b completd....3 has some prob findin the static IP on the wifi network creatd....i hope iam clear nw n sorry fr the previous confusions